# Validação de formulário com angular 6

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, angular-6

Tenho esse formulário, bem simples, apenas com um campo e um botão. Dei um required no input, e quando eu gravo com o campo vazio e/ou nulo, ele não grava(correto), mas já muda para a tela de lista. Isso seria correto, se o gravar desse ok. Então eu pergunto: Como eu valido esse formulário?
O HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="onPostCreateOperator()" style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <h1>Operadores</h1>

      <div class="required-field-block">
          <input formControlName="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" required>
          <div class="required-icon">
              <div class="text">*</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a routerLink="/operator">Criar</a></button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

**EDIT1**

Fiz conforme o colega Lucas Brogni me orientou e continua não dando o result esperado: O botão não fica disable quando o campo nome está null ou empty e ao pressionar o botão, ele não grava, mas chama a rota da lista de operadores. Veja como está meu HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="onPostCreateOperator()" style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <h1>Operadores</h1>

      <div class="required-field-block">
          <input formControlName="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" required>          
      </div>
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Criar</button> -->
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!createForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary"><a routerLink="/operator">Criar</a></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Não deveria chamar a rota, mas ficar parado e exibir uma mensagem, como não coloquei(ainda) mensagem, deveria permanecer na mesma página.

**EDIT2**

Meu .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CreateOperatorService } from '../../Services/Operators/create-operator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-operator',
  templateUrl: './create-operator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-operator.component.css']
})
export class CreateOperatorComponent implements OnInit {

  createForm :FormGroup;
  private _createOperator: Model.CreateOperators;

  constructor(private _createOperatorService: CreateOperatorService, private builder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.createForm = this.builder.group({
     name: ['', Validators.required]
   }) 
 } 

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  isValidateField(field: FormControlName, form: FormGroup){

  }

  onPostCreateOperator(){
    this._createOperator = this.createForm.value;
    this._createOperatorService.postCreateOperators(this._createOperator)
      .subscribe( success => {
        if(success.Result){

        }
      },
      error =>{
      }      
    );
  }
}
```

A idéia seria criar uma função(IsValidateField) e nela validar se o campo é válido, se é dirty ou pristine, touched e etc.. e chamar essa função no html.

**EDIT3**

Como eu faria uma função para validar meu Form/Campo. Tenho esse esqueleto e nem sei se é o caminho:

```
isValidField(field: FormControlName, form: FormGroup){
     return (form: FormGroup) => {

     };
  }
```

Nesse caso estou retornando um form, agora como eu valido os campos desse form, para retornar true se o forma estiver válido. Esta correto essa minha abordagem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode liberar o botão de criar somente quando o form estiver válido, para tal você pode fazer assim:

```
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!createForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary"><a routerLink="/operator">Criar</a></button>
```

Dentro do form no typescript faça:

```
 this.createForm = this.builder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
  })
```

Comment: Esse botão vai ficar desabilitado quando o formulário estiver correto. um ! antes do createForm.valid (`!createForm.valid`) ficaria correto.

Comment: @mutlei verdade eu ia escrever invalid mas acabei colocando errado.

Comment: @mutlei, não aconteceu nada. Fiz uma edição no post explicando.

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta com a definição do form em typescript @pnet

Comment: @pnet coloca o typescript por favor.